# Can I create weak bindings in JavaFX?

Tags: binding, javafx, weak-references

I have two bound `StringProperty` objects. I want the `Binding` to be weak, so that it becomes eligible for garbage collection as soon one of the bound objects has been GCed.

See this example:

```
StringProperty obj1 = new StringProperty("Object1");
StringProperty obj2 = new StringProperty("Object2"); 
obj2.bind(obj1);
obj2 = null;
```

How can I create a weak reference, so that the `Bindung` created in line 3 can be collected?

Answer (score 7):

Although a late anwser, I found this snippet in the [`Property.bind(...)` JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/Property.html#bind-javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue-):

> > Note that JavaFX has all the bind calls implemented through weak listeners. This means the bound property can be garbage collected and stopped from being updated.

Therefore your bindings should maintain weak references by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a BidirectionalBinding via `property1.bindBidirectional(property2)` or in your case `obj2.bindBidirectional(obj1)` this binding will be created using `com.sun.javafx.binding.BidirectionalBinding` which is implented using `WeakReference`.

If this is what you are searching, it works as expected. If you are "only" interested in an unidirectional binding, you can go on to the source code of the aforementioned class, copy its binding implementation and tailor it to your needs.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you create a custom-string-binding. Then you can handle the null-case yourself when the binding is activated.